# Getting Latitude and Longitude using different modes in android

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

### I have a Snapshot of Location Mode in android

[image]

---

Code to check location modes!

```
private void checkLocationModeSettings() {
    int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);

    switch (mode) {
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY:
            Log.d(TAG, "Sensor only mode");
            break;
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING:
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery saving mode");
            break;
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY:
            Log.d(TAG, "High accuracy mode");
            break;
        case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF:
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "Location access is disabled");
    }
}
```

---

***`QUESTIONS`***

### Possible ways i can get lat/lng if my device is set to

1. Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF
2. Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY
3. Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING
4. Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY

***Note: if Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF we cannot get lat/lng(i am not sure)***

Comment: you should not have to worry about what mode the device is on, the location manager either returns a location or not

Comment: @tyczj .... when i tested if `LOCATION_MODE_OFF` location manager wont return  a location ..... there location manager is null ! .... any possible ways i still can get lat/lng ?

Comment: uh well location manager is off so for obvious reason there wont be a location returned...

Comment: Like @tyczj said, it isn't really on you to manage these. The LocationManager will determine the best available means of getting a location and return it. If it returns null it is because it isn't able to get a location.